# Multidimensional arrays in C# parametrized on dimensions

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Is it possible (and, so how?) to parametrize a multidimensional array when the number and size of the different dimensions is unknown a priori (i.e. passed as parameters)?

If we define

```
int[] a1dim;
int[,] a2dim;
int[,,] a3dim;
```

we already know that `a1dim`, `a2dim` and `a3dim` are 1-, 2- and 3-dimensional respectively. But is it possible to specify the dimensionality of an array when a parameter is passed (e.g. a list of the sizes of each dimension)? e.g.,

```
public object GetMultidim(int[] sizes)
{
    object[/*?*/] andim = new object[/*func(sizes)?*/];
    return andim;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It already exists: [`System.Array.CreateInstance(Type, params int[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfs8044k.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Array.CreateInstance` factory methods to instantiate your arrays instead of the `[dim, dim ...]` short hand.